# EntityManager.persist() and EntityManager.merge() aren't making any changes to database when using c3p0

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, c3p0, pool

I'm working with c3p0 as a connection pool manager to hibernate. It's working well to retrieve data from database, but any insertion or update to database using JPA don't make any changes. Could someone explain why do that happens?

I'm using Jboss EAP 6 server.

persistence.xml:

```
<persistence-unit name="judzi" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

    <class>com.guizion.model.Administrator</class>
    <class>com.guizion.model.BilletPayment</class>
    <class>com.guizion.model.Client</class>
    <class>com.guizion.model.Contact</class>
    <class>com.guizion.model.DepositPayment</class>
    <class>com.guizion.model.Email</class>
    <class>com.guizion.model.ExpiredEmailLink</class>
    <class>com.guizion.model.History</class>
    <class>com.guizion.model.LastSalesReportCache</class>
    <class>com.guizion.model.Location</class>
    <class>com.guizion.model.Notification</class>
    <class>com.guizion.model.Order</class>
    <class>com.guizion.model.OrderProduct</class>
    <class>com.guizion.model.Phone</class>
    <class>com.guizion.model.Product</class>
    <class>com.guizion.model.Route</class>
    <class>com.guizion.model.User</class>
    <class>com.guizion.model.Vendor</class>
    <class>com.guizion.model.VendorProduct</class>

    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform"/>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />

        <property name="connection.autoReconnect" value="true" />
        <property name="connection.autoReconnectForPools" value="true" />
        <property name="connection.is-connection-validation-required" value="true" />

        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />

        <!-- Local -->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="****" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="****" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/judzi" />

        <!-- C3P0 -->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="100" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="5" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment" value="1" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="300" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="3000" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Dependencies (using maven):

```
...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
...
```

Methods for persist and update:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@Stateless
public class SqlRepository {

    @Inject
    private EntityManager em;

    public EntityManager getManager() {
        return em;
    }

    public <T extends BaseEntity> T add(T item) {
        if (item.hasValidId())
            return update(item);
        this.em.persist(item);
        this.em.flush();
        return this.refresh(item);
    }

    public <T extends BaseEntity> T update(T item) {
        return this.em.merge(item);
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Where's your transactional boundary?

Comment: With @ Stateless EJB I don't need to specify it. Are you talking about @ Transactional annotation?

Comment: That depends on how you are managing transactions. I asked where the boundary was. Where are you starting the transaction and there are you committing it? Whether your bean is `@Stateless` or not is not relevant.

Comment: so what does the log say? You have looked at the log haven't you?

Comment: Of course @NeilStockton. I'll put it in question body.

Comment: In runtime, the log doesn't mention anything. Follow the log during the server startup and deploy. See that c3p0 is running as expected: https://gist.github.com/rafagan/111daa0dbdf391538ab4

Comment: `HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false`. So back to my original question - where is your transactional boundary?

Comment: On an unrelated note; c3p0 is, I think, dead as a project. It hasn't had a new version since 2007 and therefore hasn't been updated to take account of new features in JDBC. I would recommend switching to a more modern connection pool, such as [Hikari CP](https://brettwooldridge.github.io/HikariCP/). Further, if you are using Mysql and JTA, you might well want to use an XA aware connection pool - like Mysql's own `MysqlXADataSource`.

Comment: Boris, as far as I know when the method scope ends, the transaction commits. It works until today, except for c3p0. I just need to add the @ Transaction annotation when I use an update or delete operation with JPQL.

Comment: Boris, thanks for the Hikari CP. I'll try using this and see what happens.

Comment: I imagine that you were using autocommit before - which is **very bad**. Adding a real connection pool, disabled this by default, which is **very good**.

Comment: @Ráfagan note that Hikari CP is **not** an XA connection pool and you are using JTA transactions. This means that your database connections will not be able to participate in the distributed transactions, if they are being used.

Comment: @BoristheSpider HikariCP is a fine Connection pool, I understand. But c3p0 is far from dead. Its most recent release c3p0-0.9.5.2 is from [Dec 2015](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.mchange%7Cc3p0%7C0.9.5.2%7Cjar)

Comment: @SteveWaldman Interesting - I hadn't seem those. I think, being an idiot, I checked our internal Nexus index rather than central. Thanks for the info.